# How might you identify which set/function is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I understand that for a function or a set to be considered a vector space, there are the 10 axioms or rules that it must be able to pass. My problem is that I am unable to discern how exactly we prove these things given that my book lists some weird general examples.

For instance: the set of all third- degree polynomials is not a vector space but the set of all fourth degree or less polynomials is? Is this because I can have $$f(x) = x^3$$ $$g(x) = 1 + x - x^3$$ $$f(x) + g(x) = 1 + x$$ 
which isn't in 3rd degree where as the fourth degree or less means I can have it not have to be in 4th degree?

Other curious sets I can't seem to discern or wrap my head around include

The set $${(x, y)}$$ where $$x>=0$$ and y is a real number.

A 4x4 matrix with symmetrical ordering except the diagonal is 0, 0, 0, 1 in descending order.

And the set of all 2x2 singular matrices.

The most confusing of all is what I like to call the modified set which changes an operation or two into something like this:

Let V be a set of all positive real numbers; determine whether V is a vector space with the operations shown below

$$x + y = xy$$
$$cx = x^c$$

If anyone could help explain why these sets break whatever axiom (because I just feel like these sets fit as a vector space but my book says otherwise) it would really help me out. I just started the vector space unit in my class and I gotta say being this clueless is scary.

Comment: It's often sufficient to show that your given set is a linear subspace.

Comment: How do you show a set is a linear subspace if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Many of your examples are incomplete. You need to specify the associated scalar field and how vector addition and multiplication by a scalar work before you can talk about the set’s being a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

A (real) vector space has an addition(like operation) with a zero element and additive inverses, and also have a multiplication(like operation) by scalar (=real numbers).

The first thing to check is the zero element. If the addition is the usual one (either among numbers, $n$-tuples, matrices, polynomials or functions), then the zero must be indeed (constant) $0$. 
This already rules out the set of symmetric $4\times 4$ matrices with diagonal $(1,0,0,0)$ (unless the addition is modified).

Next thing to verify is closure under the given addition/subtraction operation. 
The set of polynomials of degree exactly $n$, is not closed under addition, as you correctly pointed out.
The set of $(x, y)$ with $x\ge0$ is not closed under subtraction.

If the given operations are the usual addition and multiplication by scalar, we *don't have to verify* the axioms about their properties (associativity distributivity, etc.), since those are already known to be satisfied.

So, for example, the set of polynomials of degree $\le n$ is closed under the usual addition and scalar multiplication, and that's enough to state that's a vector space. In fact, in such a situation it is indeed a *subspace* of an already known vector space, now the ambient space consists of all polynomials.

Finally, if the operations are not usual, but the given set will be a vector space w.r.t. them, then there must be an *isomorphism* to an already known vector space. 
The given example $U$ with $x\hat+y:=xy$ and $c\hat\cdot x:=x^c$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$ with the usual operations, by $x\mapsto e^x, \ \Bbb R\to U$. 
[The exponential map takes addition to multiplication, its inverse is the logarithm.]

If you can't spot such an isomorphism, then you have to check the axioms one by one (which is easy in this example).

Answer (score 1):

Without too much precision, a real vector space $V$ is just a set endowed with two operations. The first operation is often denoted by $+$ and just turns $V,+$ into a commutative group. The second operation, the scalar multiplication $\cdot$, allows you to multiply real numbers with elements in $V$. Obviously you want some silly properties to hold, that is $1\cdot v=v, (\lambda+\mu)\cdot (v+w)=\lambda\cdot v+\lambda\cdot w+\mu\cdot v+\mu \cdot w$ and so on.

The important thing of a vector space is that it is a structure on a set which allows you to take linear combinations of elements, i.e. let $v_i\in V$ for each $1\leq i\leq n$ and let $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{R}$ for each $1\leq i\leq n$, then the element $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\cdot v_i$ of $V$ is defined.

Now consider the set $W=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x\geq 0\right\}$. Obviously this is a subset of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and when I say vector space I imply a sum and scalar product structure on it). The question is whether $W$ is itself a vector space for the same operations. Note that $(1,0)\in W$ but $(-1)\cdot (1,0)=(-1,0)\notin W$. Hence $W$ is not closed under linear combinations and hence it's not a vector space!

Try to figure out whether the given examples survive the test.